# Applying for 'Sole representative of international business', having overstayed previous working holiday visa

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, working-visas

My question is basically asking whether it would be possible, and likely to be granted a visa on 'Sole representative of international business' having previously overstayed a working holiday visa by 1 year. He returned to India on his own accord, at his own expense. Immigration were aware of his over stay and he was reporting in to the station once a week.

He has since gone onto join a news outlet and they are interested in sending him over for relevant material as 'Sole representative of international business'.
My question is whether (1) he would even be considered , and (2) the likelihood of being granted a visa.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions about work visas should be asked on our sister site, [expatriates.se].